# what is the meaning of this regular expression(php)

Tags: php, regex

```
$str = "Instant Oats Drink - Chocolate Flavour 165g (33g x 5)";

preg_match('/(?P<title>.*) (?P<grammars>\d+g) \((?P<portion>\d+g) x (?P<times>\d+)\)/', $str, $m);

echo "Title : " . $m['title'] . '<br />';
echo "Grammars : " . $m['grammars'] . '<br />';
echo "Portion : " . $m['portion'] . '<br />';
echo "Times : " . $m['times'] . '<br />';
```

I really don't know what meaning in preg_match. For example `"?P<title>"` , `"\d+g"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$str = "Instant Oats Drink - Chocolate Flavour 165g (33g x 5)";

`/(?P<title>.*) (?P<grammars>\d+g) \((?P<portion>\d+g) x (?P<times>\d+)\)/`

In english it would be something like this:

look for one or more characters -- call this 'title' (Instant Oats Drink - Chocolate Flavour)

--  followed by --

a space

-- followed by --

one or more numbers ending with a 'g' -- call this 'grammars' (165g)

--  followed by --

a space

-- followed by --

a parenthesis '('

-- followed by --

one or more digits (\d+) ending with a g -- call the \d+g 'portion' (33g)

--  followed by --

a space followed by an x followed by a space. ( x )

--  followed by --

one or more digits -- call this 'times' (the 5)

Comment: If I want to include space in 'title', what should i do?

Comment: Do want the title broken up more, or do you want a space in the name you are giving your subpattern?

Comment: Both ^^
1) I want to broken the title word by word, however, it is one of example, i don't know how many word in title

Comment: 2) i tried (?P<title>.* )(?P<grammars>\d+g) instead of (?P<title>.*) (?P<grammars>\d+g), it is not work.

Comment: If you do not know how many words there are in the title, just grab all of it, and run `split` on the result.  There is no (sane) way to get each token in the title in a separate group, except perhaps by putting a fixed number of optional non-space groups and hoping you never get a title with more words than you have groups for.

Answer (score 2):

from the manual of [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

*Named subpatterns now accept the syntax (?) and (?'name') as well as (?P). Previous versions accepted only (?P).*

so, `(?P<grammars>.*)` will make you have a value in `$m['grammars']`

`\d+` matches 1 or more digits, `g` matches the letter g

`.*` greedy match on any character, 0 or more times - in your case, this match will be put in the `title` or `grammars` match variable.

I recommend you read on some basic regex tutorials - the `.*` construct is a really basic one

Comment: This tutorial is great for learning named subpatterns (and everything else in that query) http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/advanced-regular-expression-tips-and-techniques/

Comment: @DallinDyer It is an advanced tutorial, is there any basic tutorial??

Comment: @Tudor I still don't know "(?P<grammars>.*)" , what is the meaning of ".*"??

Comment: Here is a quick cheat sheet that may help you out. http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/RegEx-QuickRef.htm. .* = zero or more of any character

Answer (score 2):

The meaning is this :

```
# (?P<title>.*) (?P<grammars>\d+g) \((?P<portion>\d+g) x (?P<times>\d+)\)

# 
# Match the regular expression below and capture its match into
#  backreference with name “title” «(?P<title>.*)»

#    Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*»
#       Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
# Match the character “ ” literally « »
# Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference with name “grammars” «(?P<grammars>\d+g)»
#    Match a single digit 0..9 «\d+»
#       Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
#    Match the character “g” literally «g»
# Match the character “ ” literally « »
# Match the character “(” literally «\(»
# Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference with name “portion” «(?P<portion>\d+g)»
#    Match a single digit 0..9 «\d+»
#       Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»

#    Match the character “g” literally «g»
# Match the characters “ x ” literally « x »
# Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference with name “times” «(?P<times>\d+)»
#    Match a single digit 0..9 «\d+»
#       Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
# Match the character “)” literally «\)»
```

This it the output of regexbuddy. You should use a regex helper. Helps a lot :)